# Perl grep through large file to match a string

Tags: perl

I have an array (`@array`) which has list of elements. I need to check whether these each of the elements are exists in master file or not. If the element exists in master file then in the same line of master file the string `YES` (in 5th position) should also exists. And the element should be stored in different array.

Actually my script uses two `grep` shell command to achieve this. How can I write same thing in Perl do grep.

```
...
use Data::Dumper;

my @new_array;
my @array = ('RT0AC1', 'WG3RA3');

print Dumper(\@array);

foreach ( @array ){
    my $line = `grep $_ "master_file.csv" | grep -i yes`;
    next unless($line);
    push( @new_array, $_ );
}

print Dumper(@new_array);
...
```

where master_file.csv looks like this:

```
101,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,FAULTY,NO
102,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,WORKING,YES
103,RT0AC1,NOT CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
104,WG3RA3,NOT CONNECTED,DISABLED,NO
105,WG3RA3,CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
```

So Here I am getting `$line` value as `102,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,WORKING,YES` and element `RT0AC1` is getting stored in `@new_array`.

How can I avoid using backtick(`) and two greps to achieve this. I am trying to do this using pure Perl. Also the `master_file.csv` contains millions of records.

Comment: Are the words you're looking for always in the second column of the csv file?

Comment: @Shawn yes they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the words you're looking for are in the same location, it's easy to just split up the current line on commas and see if the second column exists in a hash table, and if the fifth column is equal to `"YES"`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = shift // "master_file.csv"; # Default filename if not given on command line
my @array = qw/RT0AC1 WG3RA3/; # Words you're looking for
my %words = map { $_ => 1 } @array; # Store them in a hash for fast lookup
my @new_array;

# Use Text::CSV_XS for non-trivial CSV files
open my $csv, "<", $filename;
while (<$csv>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /,/;
    push @new_array, $F[1] if exists $words{$F[1]} && $F[4] eq "YES";
}

print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

Comment: thanks @shawn. there is warning popping up `Use of uninitialized value $F[1] in exists at script.pl line 17, <$_[...]> line ..`.

Comment: @vkk05 You have a line without commas.

Comment: Right, sometimes blank lines or lines contains without commas (single column data).

Comment: I have added these lines inside while - `next if /^\s*$/; my @F = split /,/; next unless $F[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Form *regex* to match records of interest, split line into fields and compare field #5 to **YES**. If there is a match increase a count for field #2 in `%match` hash.

Once the file processed `%match` hash will have matched records field #2 as a key and value will *reflect* how many times this field was matched with **YES** in the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %match;
my @look_for = qw(RT0AC1 WG3RA3);
my $re_filter = join('|',@look_for);

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /$re_filter/;
    my @data = split(',',$_);
    $match{$data[1]}++ if $data[4] eq 'YES';
}

say Dumper(\%match);

__DATA__
101,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,FAULTY,NO
102,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,WORKING,YES
103,RT0AC1,NOT CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
104,WG3RA3,NOT CONNECTED,DISABLED,NO
105,WG3RA3,CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'RT0AC1' => 1
        };
```

Remove `DATA` to get final code and give filename on command line to process file with data of interest

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %match;
my @look_for = qw(RT0AC1 WG3RA3);
my $re_filter = join('|',@look_for);

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /$re_filter/;
    my @data = split(',',$_);
    $match{$data[1]}++ if $data[4] eq 'YES';
}

say Dumper(\%match);
```

An alternative version based on regular expression without using `split`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %match;
my @look_for  = qw(RT0AC1 WG3RA3);
my $re_filter = join('|',@look_for);
my $regex     = qr/^\d+,($re_filter),[^,]+,[^,]+,YES$/;

/$regex/ && $match{$1}++ for <DATA>;

say Dumper(\%match);

__DATA__
101,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,FAULTY,NO
102,RT0AC1,CONNECTED,WORKING,YES
103,RT0AC1,NOT CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
104,WG3RA3,NOT CONNECTED,DISABLED,NO
105,WG3RA3,CONNECTED,WORKING,NO
```